# FCM InvalidRegistration

Tags: php, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developing an app in which I send notifications using `FCM REST API`.
But when I send the notification I always get the same error `InvalidRegistration`. 
When I googled the problem I knew that the problem is in the registration token format. so I wanna make sure if I'm sending the right token.
what I do is I authenticate users and the auth request returns.

```json
{
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "localId": "sQFWGMTlRvd8XgbxC9T6UyyKKNW2",
    "email": "01026525200@zeal.com",
    "displayName": "",
    "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjljYjU0Zjc4OTczNTU4NjU5ZTMxNGFkYzhjMTRkYzVmNjUyMTZmZmQifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vemVhbC1kZXYiLCJhdWQiOiJ6ZWFsLWRldiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTQ5ODI5ODUxNywidXNlcl9pZCI6InNRRldHTVRsUnZkOFhnYnhDOVQ2VXl5S0tOVzIiLCJzdWIiOiJzUUZXR01UbFJ2ZDhYZ2J4QzlUNlV5eUtLTlcyIiwiaWF0IjoxNDk4Mjk4NTE3LCJleHAiOjE0OTgzMDIxMTcsImVtYWlsIjoiMDEwMjY1MjUyMDBAemVhbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsImZpcmViYXNlIjp7ImlkZW50aXRpZXMiOnsiZW1haWwiOlsiMDEwMjY1MjUyMDBAemVhbC5jb20iXX0sInNpZ25faW5fcHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCJ9fQ.Uuuy7566wziSjp001WD_OwG2OdrsggwbuftCnsdpKTicVKArdayEVGq4-pBNsQOZKYNrhpTmiv86d_lbGeeuu9LNJX0xwjvslGA2EffdS1Vaf_OaBrwlp9rllTdXsIEp5wSpPUX_jSa2dck0lpU5bNPVAPjfw6_q4kmKkf6pMzjKLogGvJmtRJOuA5LMFIbJGrs57QIJfbDbghvG-etYAorgRIXwM1Xfg2eYD5s7sItwv0h9hitkH2R_Fy1yJuml51nbA6GT93YyE05QYowfmrymbfYOCYtOsfdkdL6iU0CLH8I0Cw7sQhGIx1iuQl1Wv5aNN2Z4QAiKERpt2VJ_Hw",
    "registered": true,
    "refreshToken": "ACXxpGEB6dkyDsmRVkaXrTshqAhQPZCSVC8kofhypeWDP473zIIOZQpAF_cMEQP6CaOB2PnyDiYX3cJdYAcG2Wcpyzcpij3s2TauyiaKqfYTy76EtvHDGZrW-FyHXc9fX1sRZWbW4uhslrEZ_tYy2axolmc7g3ZPfWAidqHjEjIzqS2moJTM5lXuvxBRlpZQcNXQFOGtr8E8",
    "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

so I use the `idToken` to send the notification. Is that right or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `idToken` you're using doesn't seem to be a valid registration token for FCM, hence the `InvalidRegistration` error.

You mentioned that that value (`idToken`) is from a response after authentication, which is probably what it just is. From what I know about auth, it's usually just to identify the session and expires after a specific interval (`expiresIn`).

For FCM, the needed value as a target is an actual token generated from the client side by calling `getToken`. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token):

> **Retrieve the current registration token**
>
> When you need to retrieve the current token, call getToken. This method returns null when permission has not been granted. Otherwise, it returns a token or rejects the promise due to an error.
>
> ```
>   // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
>   // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
>   messaging.getToken()
>   .then(function(currentToken) {
>     if (currentToken) {
>       sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
>       updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
>     } else {
>       // Show permission request.
>       console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
>       // Show permission UI.
>       updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
>       setTokenSentToServer(false);
>     }
>   })
>   .catch(function(err) {
>     console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
>     showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
>     setTokenSentToServer(false);
>   });
> }
> ```

The token generated usually comes in a format like:

```
 <InstanceID>:<Actual token>
```

e.g.:

```
 abcd1234:abcdefg123456
```

Double check if you're actually the correct method to generate the token.

Comment: I used the Javascript docs as reference for my answer. But I may change it accordingly if you specify which platform you're using as a client.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue..the problem was my device token column length in database table. when I change it to 255, it works.